# Store a string in a shared place, accessible to a set of applications only

Tags: android, android-studio

Imagine these applications:

1. `com.example`
2. `com.example.app1`
3. `com.example.app2`

One solution is to use `android:sharedUserId='com.example'` in both `app1` and `app2` and use the same **certificate** to sign all packages, so that all of them can access the shared preferences of the `com.example`.

However, this has a drawback. `app1` and `app2` can share something only and if only `com.example` is installed first.

Is there a way around this, so that applications `app1` to `appN` can access a shared place, only limited to them, without the need for a central useless package to be used only as a shared Linux username?

Comment: Two easy suggestions:  1)Do the exact same thing you mentioned but have app1 own it.  No need for the 3rd package.  2)Use a central server to store the data on a per account basis (or a per device bases).

Comment: @GabeSechan, that's still not possible. Because user might install `app8` first, and then install `app7`. Again, since they both use `app1` as their shared user ID, they can't reuse each other's data.

Comment: @GabeSechan your second solution is only safe if it's behind authentication and authorization. Otherwise it's not safe. Anyone can sniff the traffic and get the data.

Comment: Then your best solution is probably cloud storage.  Or failing that, have them all have the capability to store it and use a voting strategy to decide who actually does.  But then you'll still run into troubles around uninstall.  Cloud is your best solution.

Comment: They can't sniff it over HTTPS. Which if you use anything else these days is a sign of incompetence.

Comment: We do use HTTPS, and you're right. They won't be able to sniff HTTPS, but our URLs are not safe so they can understand our endpoints that we call, and they can call it themselves.

Comment: Then you're going to have to do very complicated stuff.   You could use a distributed storage strategy where everyone saves a copy and sends a broadcast to all other apps when its changed, and the other apps update themselves.  Its clunky, but it would work.  Really I'd start to challenge your two central thesis though-  that your app doesn't need a login, and that you really need this data shared.  One of those is probably wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172623/discussion-between-mohammad-rostami-siahgeli-and-gabe-sechan).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using shared preferences you can write data in a file :
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File
and that file can be stored in an internal storage which can be accessible by all the 3 applications.

Comment: Not safe at all. Safety matters here. Otherwise I/O is among the first things all developers learn.

Comment: You can use various one way encryption techniques and secured hash fuctions to encypt the data.